# How can I list the content of a zip archive, but only the first level?

Tags: archive, compression, directory

I have a big zip file and I want to know what it's contain. I know I can run:

```
zipinfo file.zip
```

but the output is too verbose and there are a **lot** of files in the sub-directories.

I want to see a list of the files in the top level.

*Example*

If the normal output is:

```
-sh-3.2$ zipinfo file.zip
Archive:  file.zip   999999999 bytes   99999 files
-rw-r--r--  2.3 unx     3894 tx defN  3-Jul-11 13:11 file1
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 23-Feb-12 21:00 dir1/
-rw-r--r--  2.3 unx      269 tx defN 23-Oct-11 14:34 dir1/file2
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 25-Sep-11 03:53 dir1/subdir1/
...
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 23-Feb-12 21:00 dir2/
...
```

I want a command that will output:

```
-sh-3.2$  <answer>
Archive:  file.zip   999999999 bytes   99999 files
-rw-r--r--  2.3 unx     3894 tx defN  3-Jul-11 13:11 file1
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 23-Feb-12 21:00 dir1/
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 23-Feb-12 21:00 dir2/
drwxr-xr-x  2.3 unx        0 bx stor 23-Feb-12 21:00 dir3/
...
```

Comment: In the question title, your usage of the word enlist is wrong. You might want to use list instead.

Comment: @JonathanGinsburg thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can filter the output with grep. Here I'm telling grep to hide all rows that contain a slash '/' and anything after the slash:

```
zipinfo file.zip | grep -v "/."
```

Comment: @dvb - many thanks ...any way to display size of dirs ? it shows 0 for 'length' column for many dirs  which I know have content.

Comment: @killjoy this worth a separate question. you might first get a list of all files and folders with their size recursively, and then use grep to get only the first level

Comment: Piping to `grep -v "/."` works also with the output of `zip -sf` or `unzip -l`

Comment: This `"/."` seemed confusing at first, I was thinking _"surely he meant `./`, but why would that work?"_. But no, it's very smart !

The pattern works by selecting everything that is not a directory, as the slash is followed by "something" (`.`), and then inverting that, so we only get directories

Answer (score 6):

Expanding and building on top of @dvb's answer, you can set the deepness level with extended regular expressions:

```
zipinfo file.zip | egrep "^([^/]*/?){<deepness-level>}$"
```

Comment: Note: this only work for ASCII file/dir names